# Hibernate - createQuery not fetching timestamp

Tags: java, hibernate, date, jpa, persistence

Envrionment: Java, Hibernate JPA provider, JPA, Oracle DB

I am trying to create a native query to fetch the data from the Oracle DB. One of the columns is a date column. The date is fetched, but the timestamp is coming out as 00:00:00. However, through an SQL browser, I can see the date and the time. How do I fetch the resultList along with the time?

```
org.hibernate.Query query = ((HibernateEntityManager) entityManager).getSession().
                                     createSQLQuery(NATIVE_QUERY).setResultTransformer(org.hibernate.transform.Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);

query.setString(0, accountNumber);;
query.setTimestamp(1, startDate).setTimestamp(2, endTime);
query.setTimestamp(3, startDate).setTimestamp(4,endTime);
List resultList = query.list();
```

The query itself (in the code above - NATIVE_QUERY) is a normal SQL query for - "Get me all user names and txn time within a given date range whether it is a new transaction or something that has changed in some form".

**select u.first_name as firstName, u.last_name as lastName, tx.start_time as txnTime from  user u, transaction tx where tx.user_id=u.user_id and tx.account_number=? and (tx.start_time > ? and tx.start_time < ? or tx.change_time > ? and tx.change_time < ?)**

```
for(Object listItem : resultList){
    Map map = (Map) listItem;
    Date txnTime = (Date)map.get("txnTime".toUpperCase()); 
   //--------> NOT FETCHING THE TIME. I get the time as 00:00:00
}
```

The domain model is very simple

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="TRANSACTION")
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(
        dynamicUpdate = true
    )
    public class Transaction{
        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(name="txn_gen", sequenceName="TXN_S")
        @GeneratedValue(generator="txn_gen")
        @Column(name="TXN_ID")
        private Long txnId;

        @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", nullable=false)
        private User user;

        @Column(name="START_TIME", nullable=false)
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private java.util.Date startTime;

        @Column(name="CHANGE_TIME")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private java.util.Date changeTime;
    }

@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(
    dynamicUpdate = true
)
public class User {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_gen", sequenceName = "USER_S")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "user_gen")
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private Long userId;    

    @Column(length=500, name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(length=500, name="LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;
 }
```

Comment: Can you show us entity classes and their Hibernate mapping? Database structure also will be useful to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Have you tried using an HQL query, rather than a native query? An HQL query would use the appropriate type, deduced from the annotations.

Comment: Using HQL over SQL worked! Its a workaround and I hope Hibernate looks into this issue of why SQL won't work correctly.